# Cannot invoke more than 64 Lambda functions at one time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, clojure, aws-lambda

I cannot invoke more than 64 synchronous lambda functions without getting an `Ops Limit: 64` exception, and I have no idea why.

There is no mention of this in the [Lambda limits documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html). In fact, it says you can have up to 1000 concurrent executions. The [lambda scaling docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/scaling.html) additionally state that temporary bursts up to 3k invocations are supported.

So why is my paltry 65 invocations causing Lambda to reject things?

**Reproducing:**

On my account I have a dead simple Lambda which sits for 5 seconds (to simulate work) and then returns the default json blob.

```py
import json
import time 

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    time.sleep(5)
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Excluding the `time.sleep` call, this is the exact code generated when you create a new Python Lambda function. So, no weirdness going on here.

**Invoking**

Now to invoke it, I just submit the invocation task into a thread pool.

```clj
(defn invoke-python [_]
  (aws/invoke
        lambda
        {:op :Invoke
         :request {:FunctionName "ExampleSlowPythonFunction"
                   :Payload (json/write-str payload)}})
```

Here's all the call is doing. Just a straight `invoke` call to AWS. (The library here is [Cognitect's AWS API](https://github.com/cognitect-labs/aws-api). But it just defers down to the REST APIs, so shouldn't matter.)

The thread pool is just one of Java's executors. I hand it a size and the tasks, and it executes said tasks in a pool of size `n`.

```clj
(defn call-it-a-bunch
  [n tasks]
  (let [pool (Executors/newFixedThreadPool n)]
    (let [futures (.invokeAll pool tasks)]
      (.shutdown pool)
      (mapv #(.get %) futures))))
```

**64 invocations: no problem**

```clj
(def sixty-four-invoke-tasks (map invoke-python (range 64)))

(call-it-a-bunch 64 sixty-four-invoke-tasks)
```

A-OK. No problemo.

**65 invocations: PROBLEM**

```clj
(def sixty-FIVE-invoke-tasks (map invoke-python (range 65)))

(call-it-a-bunch 65 sixty-FIVE-invoke-tasks
```

I will get get an `Ops limit reached: 64` on that 65th request.

I have no other Lambda's running on my account. I've tried dialing up the reserved instances on the Python Lambda Function to make *double* sure that the lambda IS available.

However, the Ops limit error remains.

Why can I not invoke my function more than 64 times concurrently despite having a bucket 1000 concurrency available on my account?

Comment: Seems like some settings or restrictions from your ops team on invoke lambda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce your problem.  I'm using regular Java.  I have your exact Python Lambda and have have a `Runnable`:

```
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.AWSLambda;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.AWSLambdaClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.InvokeRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.InvokeResult;

public class LambdaThread implements Runnable {
    private String name;

    public LambdaThread(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println( "starting thread " + name);

        Regions region = Regions.fromName("us-west-2");
        AWSLambda client = AWSLambdaClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(region).build();
        InvokeRequest req = new InvokeRequest()
                .withFunctionName("test-load");

        InvokeResult result = client.invoke(req);

        System.out.println( "result from thread " + name + " is " + new String( result.getPayload().array()) );
    }
}
```

And a runner:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class LambdaRunner {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(999);
        for (int i = 0; i < 999; i++) {
            Runnable worker = new LambdaThread("thread " + i);
            executor.execute(worker);
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
            try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch ( InterruptedException ie ) { /* ignored */ }

            System.out.println( "waiting for thread termination...");
        }
        System.out.println("Finished all threads in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + "ms");

    }
}
```

To me, the error is inline with some of the wording in Clojure in general.  What version of the Cognitect library are you using?  I can't see this message in the master branch.

If I run this with say 2000 threads I get:

Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1990"

> com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.TooManyRequestsException: Rate
>   Exceeded. (Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 429; Error Code:
>   TooManyRequestsException; Request ID:
>   b7f1426b-419a-4d40-902d-e0ed306ff120)

Nothing related to `ops`.

Comment: Thanks for the extra debugging!! I tried this on my end as well, and just as you said, everything runs fine. Upon taking a closer look, the problem was due to Cognitect's HttpClient library, which has an internal pending_ops queue sized at.... 64!